# Oracle-how to modify condition to select all if condition fails?

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

My goal is to select all the data including NULL,
if conditon fails. 
How to modify condition?

```
WITH DD AS (
SELECT 1 A FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT NULL A FROM DUAL
)SELECT * FROM DD
WHERE A =2 ????? ;  -- How to modify this condition?
```

Expected result

```
A
---
1
NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

With `UNION ALL` and NOT `EXISTS`:

```
WITH DD AS (
  SELECT 1 A FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT NULL A FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM DD
WHERE A =2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM DD
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM DD
  WHERE A = 2
)
```

The query after `UNION ALL` will return all the rows of DD only if `WHERE A = 2` fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to the "table"  only once, you can use window functions:

```
select dd.a
from (select dd.*,
             sum(case when a = 2 then 1 else 0 end) over () as cnt
      from dd
     ) dd
where a = 2 or cnt = 0;
```

This can be helpful when the "table" is actually a complicated expression and you want to ensure that it is not evaluated multiple times.